# Customers not able to register in magento 2.3.1 with error as "The customer email is missing. Enter and try again"

Tags: customer, customer-account, magento2.3.1, customer-registration

I am using magento 2.3.1 and i am trying to register customer from frontend and i am getting following error "**The customer email is missing. Enter and try again.**"

when i try to check in `_beforeSave()` from `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer` doesnt getting email id. I am getting following error when I print the customer object

```
Array
(
    [created_in] => The XXXXXX XXXXX Store
    [email] => 
    [firstname] => pradeep
    [lastname] => sanku
    [store_id] => 1
    [website_id] => 1
    [addresses] => Array
        (
        )

    [entity_id] => 
    [password_hash] => c230dfa79aedee32b5d1d4645977a806be7bb4bfd0689c120930bdb1a45c2e6e:w4cmFyPTPkTsTYTlH0vSOMQIjNzW3kFJ:1
    [parent_id] => 0
)
```

**Note:-** I had debugged more and landed at `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement.php :: public function createAccount(CustomerInterface $customer, $password = null, $redirectUrl = '')`

in this function `$customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();` this variable is coming empty.

Comment: fresh installation?

Comment: yes fresh installation with data migration from m1

Comment: @Pradip have you get any solution on it. I am stuck with the same issue.

Comment: Any solution  guys?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the name assigned to the input email tag is "email" and the id assigned is "email_address". In my case, the tag name and id were different.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an account, we will be posting data to the CreatePost controller: `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost`

This controller will extract some of the posted data (for example e-mail) using the `CustomerExtractor`. This is done on line 368 in Magento 2.4.4.

`$customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $this->_request);`

The `CustomerExtractor` will look if the attribute id is present for the `customer_account_create` form in the database table `customer_form_attribute`. Please look to see if the e-mail attribute_id is in that table for the `customer_account_create` form.

Also, it might be possible that the e-mail attribute is not assigned to the customer attributeset.